# SessionStateProxy property is empty at new Runspace object when created using Uri

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-2.0, runspace

My remote runspaces works fine when I'm using PS 3.0+ but as soon as I'm running my code using PS 2.0, `SessionStateProxy` property is null (but only when I try to create remote runspace.

```
powershell -version 2

$Uri = New-Object System.Uri("http://WIN-10NL6N4THGJ:5985/wsman")
$connectionInfo = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.WSManConnectionInfo($Uri)
$runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace($connectionInfo)

$runspace.Open()

$runspace |select *

$runspace.SessionStateProxy
```

`SessionStateProxy` property should be `System.Management.Automation.RemoteSessionStateProxy` but it is `$null`. Any clue?

Comment: HI ALIENQuake, if it works in 3.0, but not in 2.0 then it is probably a bug, try the powershell uservoice https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell

Comment: If it's a bug I doubt they will fix it in 2.0 when the current Version is 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SessionStateProxy` isn't available for remote runspaces in PowerShell 2.0. I don't have any documentation atm. to back it up, but you can verify it yourself.

Local runspace:

```
$r.SessionStateProxy.GetType().FullName
System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.SessionStateProxy
```

Remote runspace (PS 4.0):

```
$runspace.SessionStateProxy.GetType().Fullname
System.Management.Automation.RemoteSessionStateProxy
```

If you use something like dotPeek to view the code inside the `System.Management.Automation.dll v.1.0.0 (file Version 6.1.7600.16385)` which is PowerShell 2.0, then you will find the `SessionStateProxy` class that's used for local runspaces, but `RemoteSessionStateProxy` is missing. If you look inside `System.Management.Automation.dll` v.3.0.0 then you will also find the `RemoteSessionStateProxy` internal-class.

**Solution**: Upgrade PowerShell (WMF 3.0 - 5.0)

Comment: I suspect that it's a unsupported feature for PS2 and I'm counted for some more experience with c# will figure it out, thanks for detailed information about System.Management.Automation.dll SessionStateProxy class, it's the confirmation which I needed.